# CRUD for dapper dot net using dot net 3.5

Tags: orm, .net-3.5, crud, dapper

I want to use an existing CRUD extension for dapper-dot-net, but I have to use .net 3.5 for my project.
So far I have tried the following nuget packages:

- DapperExtensions - wouldn't compile.
- Dapper.Rainbow - wouldn't install.
- Dapper.SimpleCRUD - wouldn't install.
- Dapper.contrib - wouldn't compile.

Is there any other CRUD extension for dapper out there? Or is there a way to make one of those work with .net 3.5?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what features you are looking to use, but Insight.Database is similar to dapper, and we just released Insight.Database v3.1, with .NET 3.5 support.

https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database

Ignore this if you are committed to dapper. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not committed to dapper necessarily, but it does look like a very popular micro-ORM, with a lot of questions about it already answered :)
Does insight.Database support sqlite (I didn't see a provider for it on github)? Does it support CRUD operations without stored prcedures?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response...Insight supports Sqlite (and most other dbs), and you can use stored procs or inline SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Dapper has a .NET 3.5 build version available according to [the repository on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/browse/#git/Dapper%20NET35):

> Dapper NET35.csproj

Try downloading the source and compiling the 3.5 version of the project, then reference that in your solution and see if it works.

EDIT: Sorry, I see you meant that the extensions won't work with earlier versions of Dapper. Maybe try downloading the source to the one with the longest project history and compiling against Dapper inside the same project to see if you can make it work?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't get any of them to compile on their own when targeting .net 3.5. They all either use some technologies specific to .net 4, or give way too many errors when trying to compile against 3.5.